# Slow Wordpress site speed with Bluehost

Tags: google-search-console, web-hosting, wordpress, page-speed

I’m having some trouble with my site speed and I cannot figure out how to fix it. My website is jakesmathlessons.com.  It is set up on Wordpress and I use Bluehost for my hosting.  I have done the speed test through Google and the loading time is very slow.

I’ve tried compressing files and moving some files into the footer or inline CSS using a Wordpress plugin I found but this didn’t seem to help much.  Are there any other tests I can run to see exactly what is causing the slow speeds and what I can do exactly to fix it and improve load times?  I’m wondering if the hosting is slow and maybe switching hosting would improve it for me or if not what else I can do.

Comment: Questions that [only could apply to your site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and [recommendations](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for third-party resources, are both considered off-topic here. There are a number of different ways to troubleshoot and improve speed issues - try searching on `improve performance` or `improve speed` in the search box above. If you figure out something more specific that you need help with, then feel free to edit this question or ask another one.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best thing to do is get yourself off what looks like a crowded under-resourced hosting server.

It takes almost 1 second for a 301 redirect and then another second before your page even starts to download.

From https://gtmetrix.com...

[image]

Generally with hosting. you get what you pay for

Comment: Thank you that’s helpful.  What were you using to see that?  When looking for web hosting, what specific things should I be looking for that would avoid that issue?  Something that specifically says my site would be hosted on a dedicated server?

Comment: Sorry I missed it you already said where that came from, thanks!

Comment: For starters, don't buy web hosting from EIG https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endurance_International_Group